# Limit on window height when resizing with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-mavericks, multiple-monitors

I have a multi-monitor Mac desktop (4 displays each of 1920x1080 arranged in a 4x4 rectangle) and can use a mouse to open a window across all monitors, filling the whole four screen desktop.
(am running Mavericks and have disabled the "Displays have separate Spaces" checkbox)

I want to be able to so this automatically, so used AppleScript. However, the window will not open to a height greater than one of the displays (1080 pixels), even though the displays are arranged in a 4x4 matrix so that the total height of the desktop is reported as 2160 pixels. Window width is no problem and the script opens nicely across displays horizontally.

Here is the key part of the AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set bounds of first window to {0, 0, 3840, 1800}
end tell
```

There seems to be some kind of limit on the vertical size of the window. Any ideas how I can achieve automation?

Googling has pulled endless gripes about multi-monitor support on Mavericks but I can't find anything related to this particular issue.

Thanks in advance

BACKGROUND

I've tried this on two multi-monitor display configurations:

1. Early 2014 Mac Pro.
   Four external 1920x1080 monitors arranged landscape in a 2x2 rectangle.
   Reported desktop size is {0, 0, 3840, 2160}
2. MacBook Pro Retina Late 2013:
   Two external 1920x1200 monitors arranged one above the other
   (and the laptop's own 2880x1800 internal display of course)
   Reported desktop size is {0, 0, 3360, 2400}

Comment: The problem is you have too many displays :D - Actually I have a slightly different way of resizing the Windows, I could post my code if you think it might help.

Comment: I'll be very grateful for any new suggestions, thanks I'L'I. As you can see from the comment I just posted to regulus below, I'm running out of ideas here...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have multiple monitors to test this, but on my one monitor the (0, 0) point is the upper left corner of my screen. Maybe you need to adjust the second number of your bounds. My suggestion would be to open a window manually by hand. Then run this code to get the bounds. Then try to set the bounds with the returned values. Of course I still don't know if this will work but at least you'll know you're working with the proper bounds. Good luck.

```
tell application "Finder"
    return bounds of window 1
end tell
```

***EDIT***: once you know the proper bounds, you might try using System Events to resize the window. System Events doesn't know "bounds", but it does know "position" (the first 2 numbers in your bounds) and "size" (the second 2 numbers in your bounds). Try this with your numbers.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        set position of window 1 to {0, 400}
        set size of window 1 to {800, 500}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip regulus. I've played with the bounds and I think we're ok there. It seems that the origin  (0,0) is defined from the top corner of the monitor where the menu is displayed. Thus, if the menu is on the top right monitor (in the 4x4 matrix), then it is necessary to use a 'left' value of -1920 to force the window to the top left of the whole 4x4 desktop. (if that makes any sense - on reading it back, it sounded a bit convoluted!)

Comment: OK. Now at least I'm sure you know the proper bounds. I had a thought. System Events can also resize windows. See the EDIT section of my post for new code.

Comment: Thanks for the update regulus. I tried the new 'system events' technique, but with exactly the same results. Interestingly, I got a popup requesting I give Accessibility permissions to Finder. I did that, but it made no difference. Because I can resize the window across all displays manually using the mouse, I then decided to go back to basics and use the Applescript record feature to record my mouse movements and play that script. It resulted in the same (incorrect) behaviour. I'm reluctant to admit it, but this really looks like a Mavericks bug. I'll report it to Apple.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't find an answer. If the Finder and System Events can't resize the window properly, I can't think of any other programmatic way to do this. If you're certain this could be done in older versions of MacOS then it would seen to be a bug in 10.9.

Comment: I'm not certain it could be done on older versions of MacOS, and I don't have an old system easily available to try. Thanks for your help and support anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Not to revive a dead subject, but with some external dependencies it *is* possible to resize larger than the monitor resolution. You need a program called MegaZoomer [https://github.com/ianh/megazoomer] ... and you need EasySIMBL [https://github.com/norio-nomura/EasySIMBL].

Install EasySIMBL first, (can be downloaded from http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/44354/easysimbl ). Then pull down MegaZoomer from (http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/21275/megazoomer) ... copy the megazoomer package into the EasySIMBL packages dir. You will need to enable the package in SIMBL. You may have to reboot. Then run your applescript and it should work.